# Bash script does not catch error status with `set -e`

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Could someone explain please why the following simple script **does not** terminate on error status?

I would expect that **false** would return with error status and cause the script to stop as I use `set -e`

```bash
set -e
false && true
echo $?
echo Done
```

Output:

```
1
Done
```

while this one **does**:

```bash
set -e
false
echo $?
echo Done
```

Output is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is incorrect, and a big reason why [`set -e` isn't really recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). There is a *long* list of exceptions (including `&&`) to the rule that `set -e` exits on a non-zero exit status, precisely because not all non-zero exit statuses indicate an error, but simply a negative result. `grep`, for example, has a non-zero exit status simply to indicate that no match was found.

```
echo foo | grep bar && echo "Found bar"
echo foo | grep bar || echo "bar not found"
```

The assumption is that if you are examining the exit status of a command for any reason (`if`, `||`, `&&`, etc), then you are *expecting* the possibility of failure and it's *not* an error if it does.